# Selecting nearest button according to finger position in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some buttons in a row and I want to select the nearest one according to X-direction of the finger in the screen.

[image]

I have the following code...

```
struct SelectTheKey: View {

    private var sArray = ["e", "s", "p", "b", "k"]
    @State var isShowPopup: Bool = false
    @State private var dragPosition = CGPoint.zero

    var body: some View {

        VStack() {
            Spacer()
            Text("global: \(self.dragPosition.x) : \(self.dragPosition.y)")

            if isShowPopup {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(0..<sArray.count) { id in
                        Text("\(self.sArray[id])").fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(id == 2 ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                }.offset(x:40, y:0)
            }

            Text("A").frame(width: 60, height: 90)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .shadow(radius: 2)
                .padding(10)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 2, coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged { dragGesture in
                        self.dragPosition = dragGesture.location
                        if !self.isShowPopup {self.isShowPopup.toggle()}
                }
                .onEnded {finalValue in
                    if self.isShowPopup {self.isShowPopup.toggle()}
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have my mac available so I can't get you a code snippet, but here's what I'm thinking. Setup your views and calculate the total width of the device. Once that's calculated, grab the width of your views. Place those views into an array. If you know their size you calculate the center of each view from the screen size. Use that and setup an event handler to check the entire array to find the one that is closest. Trigger a touchUpInside(..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```swift
struct SelectTheKey: View {

    private var sArray = ["e", "s", "p", "b", "k"]
    @State var isShowPopup: Bool = false
    @State private var dragPosition = CGPoint.zero

    @State private var rects = [Int: CGRect]()
    @State private var selected = -1
    var body: some View {

        VStack() {
            Spacer()
            Text("global: \(self.dragPosition.x) : \(self.dragPosition.y)")

            if isShowPopup {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(0..<sArray.count) { id in
                        Text("\(self.sArray[id])").fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(id == self.selected ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .background(self.rectReader(for: id))
                    }
                }.offset(x:40, y:0)
            }

            Text("A").frame(width: 60, height: 90)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .shadow(radius: 2)
                .padding(10)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 2, coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged { dragGesture in
                        self.dragPosition = dragGesture.location
                        if let (id, _) = self.rects.first(where: { (_, value) -> Bool in
                            value.minX < dragGesture.location.x && value.maxX > dragGesture.location.x
                        }) { self.selected = id }

                        if !self.isShowPopup {self.isShowPopup.toggle()}
                }
                .onEnded {finalValue in
                    if self.isShowPopup {self.isShowPopup.toggle()}
                })
        }
    }

    func rectReader(for key: Int) -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { gp -> AnyView in
            let rect = gp.frame(in: .global)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.rects[key] = rect
            }
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
        }
    }

}
```